# (Re-)creating "numpy.sum" with numba (supporting "axis" along which to reduce)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba

I want to recreate a [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)-like function. I don't plan to recreate [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) but a similar function with the same principle: Iterate over the items and do something with each of them and then return a result.

How can I make **one** numba function that understands the "reduce along axis `x`" behaviour of the numpy-functions.

Let's say the basic function looks like this (taken from [the numba source code](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/cf8c1a2f358974e0ce25a93901c2f94193d33282/numba/targets/arraymath.py#L30)):

```
def numba_sum(arr):
    s = 0.
    for val in np.nditer(arr):
        s += val.item()
    return s
```

---

This works great if I [`numba.jit`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html#compiling-python-code-with-jit) that, but then it **doesn't support any `axis`-argument**.

[`numba.vectorize`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-vectorize-decorator) isn't much better, it offers `.reduce(axis=x)` but only if the function is binary (accepts two arguments) , which the one above is not, and even then it supports only **one scalar** axis.

[`numba.guvectorize`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator) can help, but I need to explicitly define when creating the function along which axis (if any) I want to reduce the function.

In short how can I make the function `numba_sum` work like [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), that is, it should support:

- `axis=None`,
- `axis=x` (`x` integer) and
- `axis=(x,y)`

in `nopython=True` mode?

Comment: I don't know how `numba` interacts with `nditer`.  Ideally it translates the `np.nditer` calls to the corresponding C-api ones.  In any case, `nditer` takes an `op_axes` parameter.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#outer-product-iteration.  The `cython` example on this page translates an `axis` parmeter into `op_axes` values.  `einsum` also translates its `ijk` string into `op_axis`.

Comment: You could look at https://github.com/shoyer/numbagg for inspiration, although Numba might have evolved since then.

Comment: I tried an implementation here, but it is more or less simple text generation (only works if axis are known at compile time): https://numba.discourse.group/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-an-implementation-of-a-function-at-compile-time/412

Answer (score 1):

I know the following is not the most concise or efficient implementation, but it is a working one! The general idea is that you need one loop to handle the output and other loop to aggregate the values over the indices the correspond to the output.

I have tried to minimise the use of various numpy operations inside numba keeping it closer to something implemented in C. (for the sake of clarity, np.ndindex was kept.) Some setup needs to occur before the function is called, and we just do this in plain python.

This implementation is by no means optimal or efficient, but it gets the job  done and may help with inspiration for a more efficient version.

- the indices are recomputed on each loop from the positions and the multiplies, this is really inefficient and could be improved
- the np.index operations could be replaced

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.numeric import normalize_axis_index
import numba

@numba.njit()
def _numba_sum_into(arr, out, mask_out, mask_agg, shape_out, shape_agg):
    # get the multipliers
    # these times the position gives the index in the flattened array
    # this uses the same logic as np.ravel_multi_index
    multipliers = np.ones(arr.ndim, dtype='int32')
    for i in range(arr.ndim - 2, -1, -1):
        multipliers[i] = arr.shape[i + 1] * multipliers[i + 1]
    # multiplier components
    multipliers_agg = multipliers[mask_agg]
    multipliers_out = multipliers[mask_out]
    # flattened array
    a = arr.flatten()
    # loop over the kept values
    for pos_out in np.ndindex(shape_out):
        total = 0.
        # this uses the same logic as np.ravel_multi_index
        i = 0
        for p, m in zip(pos_out, multipliers_out):
            i += p * m
        # loop over the aggregate values
        for pos_agg in np.ndindex(shape_agg):
            # this uses the same logic as np.ravel_multi_index
            j = 0
            for p, m in zip(pos_agg, multipliers_agg):
                j += p * m
            # update the total
            total += a[i + j]
        # save the total
        out[pos_out] = total
    # done!
    return out

@lru_cache()
def _normalize_axis(axis, ndim: int) -> tuple:
    if axis is None:
        axis = np.arange(ndim)
    axis = np.core.numeric.normalize_axis_tuple(axis, ndim, allow_duplicate=False)
    return axis

@lru_cache()
def _get_out_and_agg_parts(norm_axis, ndim: int, shape: tuple):
    axis = np.array(norm_axis)
    # get used dims
    mask_agg = np.zeros(ndim, dtype='bool')
    mask_agg[axis] = True
    mask_out = ~mask_agg
    # make immutable
    mask_agg.flags['WRITEABLE'] = False
    mask_out.flags['WRITEABLE'] = False
    # get the shape
    shape = np.array(shape)
    shape_agg = tuple(shape[mask_agg].tolist())
    shape_out = tuple(shape[mask_out].tolist())
    # done
    return mask_out, mask_agg, shape_out, shape_agg

def numba_sum(arr, axis=None):
    axis = _normalize_axis(axis, arr.ndim)
    # get the various shapes
    mask_out, mask_agg, shape_out, shape_agg = _get_out_and_agg_parts(axis, arr.ndim, arr.shape)
    # make the output array
    out = np.zeros(shape_out, dtype=arr.dtype)
    # write into the array
    _numba_sum_into(arr, out, mask_out, mask_agg, shape_out, shape_agg)
    # done!
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.random.random([2, 3, 4])

    print(numba_sum(arr, axis=None))
    print(numba_sum(arr, axis=(0, 1, 2)))
    print(numba_sum(arr, axis=(0, 2)))
    print(numba_sum(arr, axis=(0, -1)))
    print(numba_sum(arr, axis=0))
    print(numba_sum(arr, axis=-1))
```